# SharePoint 2013 Error on Office Web Apps

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, https, owa

I have the Office Web Apps installed and configured to use "**HTTPS**" and SharePoint 2013 also use "**HTTPS**". Both have SP1 installed.

When I execute the command `Get-SPWOPIZone` I get the result: **"external-https"**

When I try open a document in Office Web Apps i get the error "**Error on Server**". In the ULS log of SharePoint I get:

> 10/16/2014 10:42:58.76     w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:mypathhttps/layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%2FDocumentos%20Compartilhados%2Flista%20de%20e%2Dmails%2Exlsx&action=interactivepreview&wdSmallView=1)   f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.78  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajji6   High        Unable to write SPDistributedCache call usage entry.    f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.78  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=0#.w|microservicebnu\ms189, ClaimsCount=31    f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.78  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.78  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    aib35   Medium      SPShareByLinkHandler.Initialize : Not a ShareByLink request - missing access token  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.78  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    aib35   Medium      SPShareByLinkHandler.Initialize : Not a ShareByLink request - missing access token  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.79  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Claims Authentication           amcbl   Medium      Trusted provider is missing. Provider: '00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000'   f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.79  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Topology                        e5mc    Medium      WcfSendRequest: RemoteAddress: 'net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc' Channel: 'Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract' Action: 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2011/05/securitytokenservice/IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract/Issue' MessageId: 'urn:uuid:e37f26f3-279b-49b0-8de0-a350a4558af2' f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      aiv3c   Exception    System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.IO.PipeException: The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc' could not be found on your local machine.      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)     at Sy... f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      aiv3c   Exception   ...stem.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.TakeConnection(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOp...  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      aiv3c   Exception   ...erationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract.Issue(RequestApplicationSecurityToken request)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.SPApplicationSecurityTokenServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()     at Micros...  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      aiv3c   Exception   ...oft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.SPApplicationSecurityTokenServiceClient.RequestSelfIssuedToken(RequestApplicationSecurityToken rst) StackTrace:  at onetnative.dll: (sig=8299e000-0f80-4b71-8567-479075c2110d|2|onetnative.pdb, offset=28B42) at onetnative.dll: (offset=152A9) f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 4, ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation", 0f0011db "15.0.4571.0", c180aef3 "mscorlib", 0400766f "4.0.30319.0", 528fdae1 "fri nov 22 20:29:53 2013", 00005387 "00005387", 00000051 "00000051", c46dcbc9 "endpointnotfoundexception", 00215742 "aiv3c"   f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      agmxo   Exception    System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.IO.PipeException: The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc' could not be found on your local machine.      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)     at Sy... f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      agmxo   Exception   ...stem.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.TakeConnection(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOp...  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      agmxo   Exception   ...erationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract.Issue(RequestApplicationSecurityToken request)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.SPApplicationSecurityTokenServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()     at Micros...  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Application Authentication      agmxo   Exception   ...oft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.SPApplicationSecurityTokenServiceClient.RequestSelfIssuedToken(RequestApplicationSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.OAuth2.SPOAuth2SecurityTokenManager.RequestRawLoopbackToken(OAuth2EndpointIdentity endpointIdentity, JsonWebSecurityToken onBehalfOf, String applicationContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.OAuth2.SPOAuth2SecurityTokenManager.IssueLoopbackTokenString(Uri endpointAddress, SPIdentityContext identityContext, String applicationContext, DateTime& validTo) StackTrace:  at onetnative.dll: (sig=8299e000-0f80-4b71-8567-479075c2110d|2|onetnative.pdb, offset=28B42) at onetnative.dll: (offset=152A9) f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           Unified Logging Service         c91s    Monitorable Watson bucket parameters: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 4, ULSException14, 269cd32d "sharepoint foundation", 0f0011db "15.0.4571.0", c180aef3 "mscorlib", 0400766f "4.0.30319.0", 528fdae1 "fri nov 22 20:29:53 2013", 00005387 "00005387", 00000051 "00000051", c46dcbc9 "endpointnotfoundexception", 0018c5ce "agmxo"   f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ajc39   Unexpected  WOPIFrame - Unhandled exception: System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.IO.PipeException: The pipe endpoint 'net.pipe://localhost/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc' could not be found on your local machine.      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    Server stack trace:      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnectionInitiator.GetPipeName(Uri uri, IPipeTransportFactorySettings transportFactorySettings)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.NamedPipeConnectionPoolRegistry.NamedPipeConnectionPool.GetPoolKey(EndpointAdd... f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ajc39   Unexpected  ...ress address, Uri via)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.TakeConnection(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String...  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ajc39   Unexpected  ... action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)    Exception rethrown at [0]:      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.IApplicationSecurityTokenServiceContract.Issue(RequestApplicationSecurityToken request)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.SPApplicationSecurityTokenServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass2.b__0()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityServices.SPApplicationSecurityTokenServiceClient.RequestSelfIssuedToken(RequestApplicationSecurityToken rst)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.OAuth2.SPOAuth2SecurityTokenManager.RequestRawLoopbackToken(OAuth2EndpointIdentity endpointIdentity, JsonWebSecurityToken onBehalfOf, String applicationContext)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.OAuth2.SPOAuth2SecurityTokenManager.IssueLoopbackTokenString(Uri endpointAddress, SPIdentityContext identityContext, String applicationContext, DateTime& validTo)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.OAuth2.SPOAuth2SecurityTokenManager.IssueLoopbackTokenString(Uri endpointAddress, SPUser ...  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ajc39   Unexpected  ...user, String applicationContext, DateTime& validTo)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPWOPIHost.GetAccessToken(SPWeb web, Guid uniqueId, String proofKeyId, SPUrlZone zone, SPBasePermissions perms, Boolean hasEditLicense, Int64& ttl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPWOPIHost.GetAccessToken(SPFile file, String proofKeyId, SPUrlZone zone, Int64& ttl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPWOPIHost.GetWOPITargetInternal(HttpContext httpContext, SPWeb web, Object& spPrimeObject, SPWOPIAction& requestedAction, SPRegionalSettings spSettings, String& wopiAppUrl, String& wopiFavIconUrl, String& wopiAccessToken, Int64& wopiAccessTokenTtl, String& errorMessageToDisplay, String& redirectUrl)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WOPIFrameHelper.OnLoadHelper(WOPIFrame frame)     at ...  f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81* w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           WOPI                            ajc39   Unexpected  ...Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.WOPIFrameHelper.OnLoad(WOPIFrame frame)    f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2
>   10/16/2014 10:42:58.81  w3wp.exe (0x16530)                          0x247D0 SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable Erro no servidor.   f5b5c29c-d51c-408a-61b4-e3014dd71cd2

Comment: On OWA and SharePoint server, make sure "Net.Pipe Listener Adapter" Services is started on the servers. You can check it from Services console on the server....Also make sure that Security Token Service App pool started.

Comment: The service not exist in OWA Server.

Comment: what about the sharepoint server?

Comment: Was stopped. I started but to no avail.

Comment: also check the STS services from central admin as well as from IIS? also try to reset IIS

Comment: It's started. I will restart the IIS after end of commercial day.

Comment: I restart the SharePoint server, now I get the error "Something is preventing us from opening the workbook. It might be blocked for security reasons."

Answer (score 0):

Check the security token service on the OWA server:
    http://localhost:32843/SecurityTokenServiceApplication/appsts.svc

If everything is configured correctly, you should see ["Service"] and some XML 
 description.

If you see ["Server Error in '/SecurityTokenServiceApplication...'"] 
    ... run the following PowerShell:

```
  $host = Get-SPServiceHotsConfig
  $host.Provision()
  $services = Get-SPServiceApplication
  foreach($service in $services){$service.provision();
  write-host $service.name}

This will reprovision all services for the SharePoint farm. 

Now reset IIS: 
  PS C:\> iisreset /restart

...then everything should be fine after that.
```